# get traceId from zipkintracer

Tags: go, trace, zipkin, opentracing

I am using [zipkin-go-opentracing](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-go-opentracing), which is an implementation of the [opentracing](http://opentracing.io/) API for zipkin in go.

For (reasons) I need to get the traceId from a span. So the question:
given a opentracing.Span, how do I get the TraceId?
Everything I've tried has given me some kind of type assertion error.

Thanks,

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42699603/how-can-i-get-a-trace-id-from-opentracing-api

Answer (score 0):

```
import (
    "github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go"
    "github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-go-opentracing"
)
func IdFromSpan(aspan interface{}) uint64 {
    zspan := aspan.(zipkintracer.Span)
    return zspan.Context().TraceID
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but I got TraceID not defined error. It's picking up the Context from opentracing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the right way to do it but this should normally works

```
stdopentracing "github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go"
zipkin "github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-go-opentracing"

[...]

var traceID string

sp := stdopentracing.SpanFromContext(ctx)

if sp != nil {
    traceID = sp.Context().(zipkin.SpanContext).TraceID.ToHex()
}
```