# How can I get a trace ID from OpenTracing API?

Tags: trace, opentracing

In [#105](https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-java/issues/105) davidB asks:

> I would like to have read access to the Span id (SpanContext id) to be able to use it in log and in error reported (to end user,...). [skip] I need to expose the "trace id" in error message, then dev could use the trace to debug error reported by support, QA, end-user.

Answer (score 3):

In Spring I use this:

```java
Span span = tracer.activeSpan();
response.addHeader("trace-id", span.context().toTraceId());
```

Where `io.opentracing.Tracer tracer` I've injected by Spring

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the [OpenTracing API](http://opentracing.io) does not expose trace ID. It is being discussed in this issue: https://github.com/opentracing/specification/issues/24

Comment: u can get that trace ID through the next command tracer.activeSpan().context().toTraceId()

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do right now is to call `tracer.inject(null, Builtin.HTTP_HEADERS, map`. It will put all IDs with baggage (SpanContext) into the map. Then you can get ID by its name. However this solution is not vedor neutral.

Other solution is to cast `SpanContext` into specific implementation and get the IDs by getter (if there is any)

Answer (score 0):

Ben has offered a new way to provide this id. ref: https://github.com/opentracing/specification/issues/24#issuecomment-286261320